# Can I do an iPhone application that uses a language different than the user's setting?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, localization, internationalization

I'm developing an iPhone application and want to set a location for it different from the user location. I want to have all the files for the internationalization as Apple tell me to do BUT I want to be able to choose the language.

Ex: The user is using German but I want my application to be in English!

I want the user to set the language only for the application, no matter the language chosen in the phone, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not using the framework classes for internationalization. You would have to build your own plumbing for changing labels, buttons, etc throughout your application.

Answer (score 1):

The language is loaded from NSUserDefaults. According to [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/68139-localization-testing.html), you can override it with something like `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"] forKey:@"AppleLanguage"]` and relaunching the app.

Now, the trouble is you need to relaunch the app! One *terrible* way might be something like this (untested):

```
UIApplication * app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app openURL:...];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil userInfo:nil];
[app.delegate applicationWillTerminate:app];
exit(0);
```

where `...` is an HTTP URL that redirects to a custom URL scheme that your app handles (ewwww).

I do not know of an easy way to reload the UI/languages without relaunching the app.